# Xrandr Fix: I need help with HDMI resolution

Tags: nvidia, display, hdmi, display-resolution, hdtv

I need some help. I have my Ubuntu 14.04 computer connected to my 40" Samsung HDTV with a resolution of 1920x1080 and every time I start up my computer the top and bottom keep getting cut off. I've tried using this to resolve it:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set underscan on
```

And it works. But once I shut down my pc and restart it, it reverts back to where the top and bottom of the scren are cut off. Actually its on all sides that gets cut off.

Is there a way to prevent the system from reverting back to this resolution without having to constantly input the xrandr command or by not turning off the computer?

There are a lot of questions regarding this, but I haven't seen a fix to prevent this resolution issue from happening again, without leaving the computer on. Is there a permanent way of adjusting the resolution?

Comment: You could always add that command to your startup, then you no longer have to worry about it since you know that this works.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login/48327#48327